# Проблема при передачи данных через SocketChannel

Tags: java, сокет

Передаю данные от сервера к клиенту через `SocketChannel`. Размер буфера - 10кбайт = 10240 байт. После получения `ByteBuffer` получаю из него строку, строку перевожу в `JSONObject` и дальше уже обрабатываю данные. Так вот дело в том, что `ByteBuffer` часто приходит битый, и его невозможно конвертировать в JSONObject, хотя никаких ошибок на момент записи\чтения из канала нет. Как передавать данные, соблюдая их целостность? Я думал ввести в пакет контрольную сумму, но это будет требовать дополнительных вычислительных ресурсов. Подскажите как быть в такой ситуации.

И так, код чтения:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

public String readLine() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int k;
    do {
        buffer.clear();
        k = socketChannel.read(buffer);
        buffer.flip();
        CharBuffer charBuff = charset.decode(buffer);

        for(int i=0; i<charBuff.limit(); i++)
            sb.append(charBuff.get());
    } while(k == 1024);
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Код записи:

```
public void writeLine(String string) {
    socketChannel.write(charset.encode(string));
}
```

Comment: @Руслан Молчанов, что *конкретно* означает "битый"?

Скорее всего данных больше, чем размер буфера или пришла только их часть, а остаток буден передан позже. Данные надо читать в цикле, пока не закончатся и уже **все** переводить в JSONObject.

Как определить логический конец порции данных для JSONObject  - это задача Вашего прикладного протокола.

Comment: @avp "Битый" значит, что может отсутствовать какой-нибудь символ, что критично в данном случае. А если запросить данные повторно, то они могут прийти в нормальной форме. Сейчас попробую реализовать получение данных в цикле

Comment: @Руслан Молчанов, вот теперь видно.

    while(k > 0); // не 1024

Думаю проблема в этом. Или Вы посылаете всегда данные с размером кратным 1024?

Кстати, в этом случае Вы закончите цикл по закрытию сокета передающей стороной.

Если же за одно соединение вам надо передать несколько Json, то либо шлите код разделителя (допустим 0x01) и анализируйте его в цикле `for` для `append`, либо передавайте перед Json его длину в байтах.

Comment: @avp если я сделаю while(k > 0), то sc.read(...) будет блокировать поток тогда, когда данные кончатся

Comment: Это я описал в предыдущем комментарии. 

Реально надо обсудить весь протокол обмена (алгоритм задачи).

Comment: @avp Сложно все объяснить по мелочам, но проще так: клиент авторизуется и запрашивает данные у сервера, сервер вытаскивает их из БД и отправляет клиенту, и т.д. В качестве языка обмена данными выбран JSON.

Comment: @Руслан Молчанов, т.е. если я правильно понял, то по оодному открытому соединению выполняется несколько запрос-ответов.

Если сервер Ваш (т.е. доступен в исходных кодах) и размер персылаемых данных известен до начала их передачи, то проще всего перед и запросом и ответом передавать их длину (лучше в поле фиксированного размера и в символьном виде).

Если размер неизвестен, то в конце передаете байт-разделитель (например 0x01), которого не может быть в данных. Это будет нормально работать (с минимальными изменениями структуры программы) если всегда один запрос - один ответ (и т.д.)

(места нет

Comment: @avp Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Сделал!!! только вместо 0x01 взял символ серпа и молота ((char)9773)
Теперь код выглядит так:

        do {
            buffer.clear();
            sc.read(buffer);
            buffer.flip();

            if(buffer.limit() == 0) return null;

            CharBuffer charBuff = cd.decode(buffer);

            for(int i=0; i<charBuff.limit(); i++) {
                char ch = charBuff.get();
                if(ch == (char)9773) finish = true;
                else sb.append(ch);
            }

        } while (!finish);

Answer (score 2):

Это примерный перевод из описания как работает Stream-based Transport

> В потоке на основе транспорта, таких
> как TCP / IP, полученные данные
> записываются в буфер приема сокета. К
> сожалению, буфер потока на основе
> транспорта не является очередью
> пакетов, это очередь байтов. Это
> означает, что даже если вы отправили
> два сообщения в виде двух независимых
> пакетов, операционная система не будет
> относиться к ним как два сообщения,
> она их воспринимает просто как набор
> байтов. Таким образом, нет никакой
> гарантии, что то, что вы читаете
> именно то, что прислал Ваш удаленный
> узел. Например, предположим, что TCP /
> IP стек операционной системы получил
> три пакета:
>
> |  ABC  |  DEF  |  GHI  |
>
> В связи с этим общее свойство потока
> на основе протокола, есть высокая
> вероятность их читать в следующей
> фрагментированной форме в Вашем
> приложении:
>
> |  AB  |  CDEFG  |  H  |  I  |
>
> Таким образом, приемная часть,
> независимо от этого на стороне сервера
> или на стороне клиента, должны
> дефрагментировать данные, полученные в
> одном или более пакетах, которые могут
> быть легко поняты логикой приложения.

Обычно для того чтобы понять когда байты одного пакета закончились вставляют "символ окончания пакета" (он сугубо условный и определяется Вами), например 0x01.
Иногда в первых байтах пакета шифруют его длину и вычитывают столько сколько указано.

Comment: Ваш 1 отправленный пакет может превратится в два на стороне получателя и Вы не сможете повлиять на это. Далеко ли находится клиент от сервера ? Обычно пакеты начинают разбиваться на части при повышении трафика.

Comment: если Вы используете TCP, то данные не могут потеряться (кроме редких случаев, связанных с ошибками в реализации драйверов). Они либо приходят, либо нет.

Показывайте код, который читает данные. Там 99.9% ошибка.

Comment: @Руслан Молчанов попробуйте преобразовать полученные данные в строку, а не в JSONObject. Должно получится что то типа : 

{"age":29,"messages":"msg"}

Может Вы увидите чего не хватает.

Comment: @Руслан Молчанов, а покажите как Вы **отсылаете** данные. Может сразу чего хорошего подскажем.

Comment: посмотрел код. k=1024 может быть равным только в том случае, если read прочитал 1024 байта. Как только было прочитано другое кол-во - произойдет выход.

У Вас размер данных заранее неизвестный?

Comment: побоку, какой размер буфера. Почитайте [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer) внимательнее. Там сказано, что даже если пришло достаточно данных, read не обязан заполнить буфер полностью.

>>A read operation might not fill the buffer, and in fact it might not read any bytes at all. Whether or not it does so depends upon the nature and state of the channel.

Поэтому Ваш подход будет более-менее работать на локальном компьютере, кое-как в локальной сети и практически `146%` глючить в мобильных сетях.

Comment: @kovadim !!! Вы совершенно правы! Эта проблема как раз-таки на мобильном устройстве. Клиент под ОС Android. А как стоит реализовать этот алгоритм?

Comment: Вот поэтому ответьте на мой вопрос выше - размер данных передается или нет? или как будете определять конец данных (может после получения пакета, сервер закроет соединение).

Если же json пакеты передаются один за другим, то придется интегрировать парсер.

Comment: размер данных не передается, есть идея включить его в пакет первым байтом. Или ограничить прием данных до тех пор, пока не встретится какой-нибудь символ. Да, язык сообщений JSON - поэтому все сообщения только в этом формате. Естественно и к клиенту и к серверу подключены библиотеки(org.json), которые помогают обрабатывать JSON строку в JSONObject.